# Get a single value from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I need to get the access level for the current page in a Joomla site. I'm able to get the page id using:

```
/* Define $jinput */
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

/* Get the current page id */
$page= $jinput->get('id');
```

Now, I want to query the database to return the access level for the current page. The table content looks like:

```
page_id | access | ...
1234    | 10     |...
```

So page 1234 has an access id of 10. This is what I tried to get the 10:
/* Open a connection */

```
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass');
    if(!$link){
    echo "No connection";
    exit();
    }

    if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8'))
    {
      echo 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
      exit();
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($link, 'datab')){
        echo "Can't find database";
    exit();
};

/* Find the access level of the current page */

$query = "SELECT access FROM content WHERE id=$page";

try {
    $result=$link->query($query);   
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    $error="Error".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This seems incredibly complicated to get a single value from a page, but it doesn't work! I know the query is correct because I tested it in PHP my admin.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_*` to access the database? Have a read of the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) first

Comment: Because I always get lost in Joomla documentation. I know I can also use $link=JFactory::getDbo(); but the result is the same. Is there a quick way to get to the page access level? Like: $page= $jinput->get('access');

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: @Lodder: I'm using 2.5.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$access = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->access;
echo "Access level = " . $access;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Now where the hell is that on Joomla documentation?

Comment: Not every single thing for Joomla is on the documentation page. The first question I answered regarding menu items, I had a look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page) and then started messing around with a few things on my localhost to get a feel for what was possible :)

Comment: For example: `$app->getMenu()->getActive()` is used to access the default menu item as mentioned on the Joomla docs link I provided above. Then all you have to do is look at the columns for the `#__menu` database table and make the addition. So it would then end up looking like: `$app->getMenu()->getActive()->access;` or `$app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;` etc

Comment: Yes, I got the first part: ($app->getMenu()->getActive(). But my initial idea was to query the #__content table to get the access level.

Comment: Hey, perhaps you can also help with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894230/joomla-get-the-user-group-from-the-page-access-level-using-php

Comment: I also tried: $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$access = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->access;

$db = JFactory::getDbo(); //Abrir ligação
$query = $db->getQuery(true); //Criar um objeto query
$query->select($db->quoteName('rules'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__viewlevels'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('id')=$access);