# Joomla: get the user group from the page access level using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

In Joomla 2.5.16:

1. Suppose user 100 belongs to user groups 14 and 16.
2. Suppose that the page he's currently viewing has an access level id of 6.
3. According to the table 'viewlevels' in the MySQL database, access level 6 is available for groups 8, 16 and 17

My goal is to find the "right" user group for this page. Since the user belongs to 2 user groups and one of them (16) is contained in the array of groups allowed to see this page, how can I query the database to find that group?

I tried:

```
$usr_id=100;
$access=6;

$query(SELECT rules from 'viewlevels' WHERE ???);
```

Table viewlevels has a structure like:

```
ID   | rules
6   |[8,16,17]
```

Table user_usergroup_map has a structure like:

```
User_id   |Group_id
100   |14
100   |16
```

Any help, please?

Comment: So you want to find out if the user has access to a specific page?

Comment: No, because the user belongs to 2 user groups, I need to find which one corresponds to the page he's viewing.

Comment: The query should be like: Get the rules array from table 'viewlevels' where id=$access and then loop that array and return the number that is contained in table 'user_usergroup_map' field group_id where user_id=$usr_id. Now, how to translate this into SQL is what is puzzling me.

Comment: I'm too tired to even think right now, will have a crack at it tomorrow if someone else hasn't already

Comment: Ok, no problem, I'll keep trying in the meantime. Thank!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `#__viewlevels` AS `a` 
INNER JOIN `#__usergroups` AS `b` 
ON `a`.`rules` LIKE CONCAT('%',b.id,'%') 
INNER JOIN `#__user_usergroup_map` AS `m` 
ON m.group_id=b.id 
WHERE m.user_id = 100
```